# Грузит процессор из-за запроса PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, производительность, оптимизация-сайтов, cpu

Грузит очень сильно процессор из-за запроса такого:

```
if(($banners = $this->app->cache5min->get($key_cache)) === NULL) {
        $find_items = array();
        $banners = $this->app->db->fetchAll("SELECT b.id, b.active, b.richmedia, b.rich_position,
        b.ip_limit, b.cookie_limit, b.cookie_interval,
        b.day_limit, b.limit_interval, b.frequency,
        b.close_btn, b.use_geo, bpl.s_x, bpl.s_y
        FROM bs_items_places AS bp
            JOIN bs_items AS b ON b.id = bp.item_id
            JOIN bs_places AS bpl ON bpl.id = bp.place_id
        WHERE b.active = 1 AND b.date_start < '".$dateNow."' AND b.date_stop > '".$dateNow."'
            AND bpl.active = 1 AND bp.place_id = {$idpl}
            AND (IF((time_from!='00:00:00' AND time_to!='00:00:00'),
        (time_from<='".$dateTimeNow."' AND time_to>='".$dateTimeNow."'),1))
        ORDER BY b.frequency DESC, b.day_limit DESC");
        foreach($banners AS $bnr) {
            $find_items[$bnr['id']] = $bnr;
        }
        $banners = $find_items;
        $this->app->cache5min->save($key_cache,$banners);
    }
```

Из-за этого сайт очень долго грузиться, как комментирую этот кусок кода, сразу нагрузка спадает. Может кто помочь решить эту проблему?

В топе много запросов типа

```
SELECT `bs_items_ip`.`id`, `bs_items_ip`.`item_id`, `bs_items_ip`.`place_id`,
       `bs_items_ip`.`date_show`, `bs_items_ip`.`ip`, `bs_items_ip`.`shows`
FROM `bs_items_ip` WHERE `bs_items_ip`.`item_id` = 177 AND `bs_items_ip`.`ip` = '89.149.79.224'
    AND `bs_items_ip`.`date_show` = '2017-06-23' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: А какой процесс ест процессор, mysql ? Возьмите сам запрос, подставьте в него типовые параметры и выполните в MySQL, посмотрите на сколько тормозит. После этого сделайте `explain текст-запроса`, получившийся план выполнения приложите к вопросу. Кроме того может (и скорее всего) понадобится структура таблиц, участвующих в запросе, со всеми индексами

Comment: Мне еще кажется помимо проверки ключевых полей и индексов, еще надо пересмотреть условия и структуру JOIN нужна ли она. На более наглядные переделать.
К примеру b.date_start < '".$dateNow."' AND b.date_stop > '".$dateNow."' можно переписать как $dateNow between b.date_start and b.date_stop. То, что там идет с IF - это точно так нужно оформить?
И конечно же ORDER BY - его лучше выполнять уже на сформированных данных. Т.е. select t.* from (ваше тут все)  t Order by t.frequency DESC, t.day_limit DESC.
У вас запрос идет по полям дат, их можно проиндексировать. Даты числом хранятся в БД.

Comment: @IvanZakirov Строгие `<` и `>` в between не преобразуются, потому что он `<=` и `>=`. Кроме того на старых версиях MySQL оптимизатор неправильно работал с between из за чего он оказывался в разы медленнее `<>`. `ORDER BY` в текущем запросе в люмом случае выполняется после остальных операций, SQL по другому и не умеет, и заключение запроса еще в один подзапрос ничего не изменит.

Comment: Все запросы, о которых подозреваете, что они тормозят - делайте для них explain и смотрите получившийся план выполнения, не видя его пытаться что либо оптимизировать в БД бесполезно